# Archiving a repository on VSTS

Tags: azure-devops

We have an app that was originally built in .NET Framework and we manage it through a repository on VSTS.

We now converted it to .NET Core and I want to create a new repository for it on VSTS using the original name we used for the .NET Framework version. I also do want to keep/archive the original repository.

- Is there a way to archive a repository on VSTS?
- If I rename the old repo and create a new one for our new code using the original name, would that cause any conflicts?

Comment: Are you using Git or TFVC?

Comment: I'm using TFVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to archive a repository on VSTS?

No, since repositories (TFVC/Git) on VSTS is already VCS (Version Control System) hosted on VSTS, you can treat itself as archived.

> If I rename the old repo and create a new one for our new code using
>   the original name, would that cause any conflicts?

For TFVC repo, you can’t rename the original repo.

For Git repo, you can rename. And if you create a new git repo name it as the origin name afterwards, there has no conflicts. You just should note that the your build definition with the original repo will be changes to build other project.

Comment: I bump into this issue recently and saw Microsoft closed every request related to this topic with the same answer. I think the request is about mirroring the "archive" behavior of github which as nothing to do with git itself but is more about making something read-only on the distant repo (devOps). Why isn't it a desirable feature ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest thing to archive available in Azure DevOps is marking a repository as "disabled". To do so:

1. Go to Project Settings and then click on “Repositories”
2. Click on the Repository which needs to be archived
3. Click on Settings and then turn on the option “Disable Repository”

[image]

Once the repository is disabled, if anyone tries accessing the repository they would get an error message stating that the repository has been disabled. So it's still there but you can't see the code anymore which is where the functionality gets away from "GitHub archiving".