# Is there a way in VSTS to disable a git repository?

Tags: git, azure-devops

I created a new project and imported the code from a different project's git repo, I now want to disable the old repo, in other words:not allow any check ins or check outs from that repository ?
is there an easy way to do that without going through permissions or branch policies ?

Comment: or delete it?...

Comment: Isn't that exactly what permissions are for?

Comment: Why would you not use permissions or branch policies to do this?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Archiving a repository on VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45850700/archiving-a-repository-on-vsts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but you can **rename it**, this will change the URL and break anyone referencing it, however the repo is still there should you need to recover/view history under the renamed url.

[image: Rename Repository]

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question as people would still be able to commit to the repository once they find it.